# Chrome: z-index of 9999 still shows behind dynamic JS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dynamic, z-index

So this is one of the things I just can't figure out about Chrome...

I have a `ul` menu with a sibling `ul` menu for a sub-menu and even with i's `z-index` set to 9999, the items show behind any dynamic JS content such as YouTube Chromeless player and Nivo Slider.

Does anyone know what the solution to this is?

Comment: Assuming that the two mentioned elements are Flash elements, you'll need to set the `wmode` parameter for the embedded flash to `transparent` or `opaque`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YouTube Flash player? It always has precedence because it is drawn in a reserved space by Flash, not by the browser. By default, it's drawn over everything.

Add [`wmode="opaque"`](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#main_BrowserSupportForWmodes) to the `object`. This changes it from its default `window`, meaning it will be drawn in respect to the `z-index` property and the like.

Comment: Thanks for that... but what about Nivo Slider? It seems that the dynamically added content ignores z-index.